# SVN problems after migration with CVS2SVN

Tags: svn, file, merge, cvs, cvs2svn

We´ve migrated from CVS on AIX to SVN on Linux via CVS2SVN. The migration seems to have went well but when working in SVN we get a lot of Tree Conflicts that doesn´t seem to be conflicts at all? Looking at the revision graphs, one can see that the graph for e.g.  trunk and a branch isn´t the same, i.e. they contain different sets of revisions of the file. Either of the 3 ways to resolve this conflict when merging in TortoiseSVN leaves the revision graphs separate, they cannot be "melted" together. Could it be that CVS2SVN didn´t understand that a file in different branches is the same even if the file system path is the same? Anyone who has experienced this? Thanks, Bjorn

Comment: Can you give us an example some operations you do, from start to finish, that produce such tree conflicts? It sounds to me as you're doing something wrong, but with only the description of the end result it's hard to point out what.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to be aware of that SVN is different from CVS. The first things is SVN is changeset based whereas CVS is file based. This is a big different in thinking of branches etc. as well. The Revision graph can only be correctly if you start from trunk in SVN. What you identified as different sets of revisions of a file means only that on the branch a file has been modified at different times than on trunk for example. To the questions of tree conflicts: How do created the branches and how do you try to merge the branch together?

Comment: This means, as I understand you, that the assumption to be able to continue working in SVN with branches created in CVS before migrating to SVN is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, cause i migrated many repository from CVS to SVN but they started in SVN with branching etc.

Comment: CVS branches are *definitely* converted into Subversion branches by cvs2svn, and after the conversion it is possible to work with them as you would expect in the Subversion world.